# Ignore applicationId not included in google-services.json

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, crashlytics

I am trying to integrate Firebase Crashlytics into my Android (Kotlin) project. I have two basic flavors: debug and release.

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            debuggable true
        }
    }
```

As you can see, one of them has an applicationIdSuffix of `".debug"`, so release package name is `"com.something.app"` and debug package name is `"com.something.app.debug"`.

However, on Firebase project I have only one app, the release one, added `(com.something.app)`.
And now, after integrating Crashlytics, when trying to build debug flavor, I get `"No matching client found for package name com.something.app.debug"`.

The problem is, I don't want Crashlytics in debug, and I don't want to create separate app for it in Firebase Console. Is there a way to ignore unknown (not specified in google-services.json) applicationId when using Google Services?

Comment: You really should have different projects for development and release.  You will avoid a lot of problems that way. They can each have different configurations.

Comment: Please contact support they'll be able to activate these for you.

Comment: I'm interested too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: i have no problem for having crashlytics in both debug and release, is there anyway for the google service to accept two applicationIds (dynamically switches )?